# H2 database in Tomcat with Server Mode and Automatic Mixed Mode when using Activiti BPM with a Spring application context

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, h2, activiti

When deploying the `war` file I am stuck on the following error:

```
INFO: Loading XML bean definitions from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/beans.xml]
Exception in thread "H2 TCP Server (tcp://127.0.1.1:56099) thread" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/h2/mvstore/db/TransactionStore$1
```

In the Maven dependencies/jars I am able to see the `org.h2.mvstore.db.TransactionStore` Class inside the file `h2-1.4.178-sources.jar`.

**What I am trying to achieve is getting up and running a H2 database in [Server Mode](http://h2database.com/html/features.html#connection_modes) using the [Automatic Mixed Mode](http://h2database.com/html/features.html#auto_mixed_mode).** I would like to share this "H2 instance" among multiple `war` applications (i.e. the Activiti Explorer and my own Spring MVC Java application).

- Should I "start" somehow this H2 instance that I am expecting running in the Tomcat server? I thought the answer is no after reading the documentation regarding the "Mixed Mode".
- Is the following "Spring transaction stuff" (see below) getting Tomcat "blind" to the `TransactionStore` class provided in the Jar file with Maven?

Regarding the transactions in the Spring application context (needed when integrating an H2 database with Activiti using the dedicated classes defined under the "activiti-spring" package) I am currently not able to get them working. If I comment out the `tx` stuff (see below) then I am getting the following compiling error in the XML file in every place where a bean class is defined:

```
Build path is incomplete. Cannot find class file for org/aopalliance/intercept/MethodInvocation
```

The Spring application context is (see also I am using the Activiti integration with Spring):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.0.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="com*" />

    <!-- 
    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManagerServerMode"/>
    -->

    <bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix">
            <value>/WEB-INF/views/</value>
        </property>
        <property name="suffix">
            <value>.jsp</value>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <!-- <bean id="dataSourceServerMode" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"> -->
    <bean id="dataSourceServerMode"
        class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.SimpleDriverDataSource">
        <!-- <property name="driverClassName" value="org.h2.Driver" /> -->
        <property name="driverClass" value="org.h2.Driver" />
        <property name="url"
            value="jdbc:h2:~/Klappo/Dev/Activiti/databases/shared-testing-db;AUTO_SERVER=TRUE" />
        <property name="username" value="sa" />
        <property name="password" value="" />
    </bean>
    <bean id="transactionManagerServerMode"
        class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSourceServerMode" />
    </bean>
    <bean id="processEngineConfigurationServerMode" class="org.activiti.spring.SpringProcessEngineConfiguration">
        <!-- <bean id="processEngineConfigurationServerMode" class="org.activiti.engine.impl.cfg.StandaloneProcessEngineConfiguration"> -->
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSourceServerMode" />
        <property name="transactionManager" ref="transactionManagerServerMode" />
        <property name="databaseSchemaUpdate" value="true" />
        <property name="history" value="full" />
        <property name="jobExecutorActivate" value="false" />
        <property name="mailServerPort" value="5025" />
    </bean>
    <bean id="processEngineServerMode" class="org.activiti.spring.ProcessEngineFactoryBean">
        <property name="processEngineConfiguration" ref="processEngineConfigurationServerMode" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="dataSourceInMemory" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource">
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:h2:mem:activiti;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=1000" />
        <property name="driverClassName" value="org.h2.Driver" />
        <property name="username" value="sa" />
        <property name="password" value="" />
    </bean>
    <bean id="processEngineConfiguration"
        class="org.activiti.engine.impl.cfg.StandaloneInMemProcessEngineConfiguration">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSourceInMemory" />
        <property name="databaseSchemaUpdate" value="true" />
        <property name="history" value="full" />
        <property name="jobExecutorActivate" value="false" />
        <!-- mail server configurations -->
        <property name="mailServerPort" value="5025" />
    </bean>
    <bean id="processEngine" class="org.activiti.spring.ProcessEngineFactoryBean">
        <property name="processEngineConfiguration" ref="processEngineConfiguration" />
    </bean>

</beans>
```

The relevant part of the Maven dependencies in the `pom.xml` file is:

```
<properties>
    <activiti-version>5.11</activiti-version>
    <spring.version>4.0.1.RELEASE</spring.version>
</properties>

    [...]

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.activiti</groupId>
        <artifactId>activiti-engine</artifactId>
        <version>${activiti-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.activiti</groupId>
        <artifactId>activiti-spring</artifactId>
        <version>${activiti-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
        <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.178</version>
    </dependency>
```

The full stack trace if needed:

```
Exception in thread "H2 TCP Server (tcp://127.0.1.1:56099) thread" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/h2/mvstore/db/TransactionStore$1
    at org.h2.mvstore.db.TransactionStore.getChanges(TransactionStore.java:511)
    at org.h2.mvstore.db.TransactionStore$Transaction.getChanges(TransactionStore.java:800)
    at org.h2.engine.Session.rollbackTo(Session.java:602)
    at org.h2.command.Command.executeUpdate(Command.java:278)
    at org.h2.server.TcpServerThread.closeSession(TcpServerThread.java:178)
    at org.h2.server.TcpServerThread.close(TcpServerThread.java:210)
    at org.h2.server.TcpServerThread.run(TcpServerThread.java:169)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: General error: "java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/h2/mvstore/db/TransactionStore$1" [50000-178]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:344)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:167)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.convert(DbException.java:290)
    at org.h2.server.TcpServerThread.sendError(TcpServerThread.java:222)
    at org.h2.server.TcpServerThread.run(TcpServerThread.java:155)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/h2/mvstore/db/TransactionStore$1
    at org.h2.mvstore.db.TransactionStore.getChanges(TransactionStore.java:511)
    at org.h2.mvstore.db.TransactionStore$Transaction.getChanges(TransactionStore.java:800)
    at org.h2.engine.Session.rollbackTo(Session.java:602)
    at org.h2.command.Command.executeUpdate(Command.java:278)
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcPreparedStatement.execute(JdbcPreparedStatement.java:199)
    at org.h2.server.TcpServer.addConnection(TcpServer.java:140)
    at org.h2.server.TcpServerThread.run(TcpServerThread.java:152)
    ... 1 more

    at org.h2.engine.SessionRemote.done(SessionRemote.java:610)
    at org.h2.engine.SessionRemote.initTransfer(SessionRemote.java:129)
    at org.h2.engine.SessionRemote.connectServer(SessionRemote.java:434)
    at org.h2.engine.SessionRemote.connectEmbeddedOrServer(SessionRemote.java:348)
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.<init>(JdbcConnection.java:107)
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.<init>(JdbcConnection.java:91)
    at org.h2.Driver.connect(Driver.java:74)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.SimpleDriverDataSource.getConnectionFromDriver(SimpleDriverDataSource.java:140)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.getConnectionFromDriver(AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.java:155)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.getConnection(AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.java:120)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.doGetConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:111)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.TransactionAwareDataSourceProxy$TransactionAwareInvocationHandler.invoke(TransactionAwareDataSourceProxy.java:225)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy178.getMetaData(Unknown Source)
    at org.activiti.engine.impl.cfg.ProcessEngineConfigurationImpl.initDatabaseType(ProcessEngineConfigurationImpl.java:526)
    at org.activiti.engine.impl.cfg.ProcessEngineConfigurationImpl.initDataSource(ProcessEngineConfigurationImpl.java:487)
    at org.activiti.engine.impl.cfg.ProcessEngineConfigurationImpl.init(ProcessEngineConfigurationImpl.java:332)
    at org.activiti.engine.impl.cfg.ProcessEngineConfigurationImpl.buildProcessEngine(ProcessEngineConfigurationImpl.java:310)
    at org.activiti.spring.SpringProcessEngineConfiguration.buildProcessEngine(SpringProcessEngineConfiguration.java:60)
    at org.activiti.spring.ProcessEngineFactoryBean.getObject(ProcessEngineFactoryBean.java:56)
    at org.activiti.spring.ProcessEngineFactoryBean.getObject(ProcessEngineFactoryBean.java:32)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.doGetObjectFromFactoryBean(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:144)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.getObjectFromFactoryBean(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:103)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getObjectForBeanInstance(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1514)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:315)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:195)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1014)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:957)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:855)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:480)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:289)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1185)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:304)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:300)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:195)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:700)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:760)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:482)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:403)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4939)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5434)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:633)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:976)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1653)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Exception in thread "H2 TCP Server (tcp://127.0.1.1:56099) thread" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/h2/mvstore/db/TransactionStore$1
    at org.h2.mvstore.db.TransactionStore.getChanges(TransactionStore.java:511)
    at org.h2.mvstore.db.TransactionStore$Transaction.getChanges(TransactionStore.java:800)
    at org.h2.engine.Session.rollbackTo(Session.java:602)
    at org.h2.command.Command.executeUpdate(Command.java:278)
    at org.h2.server.TcpServerThread.closeSession(TcpServerThread.java:178)
    at org.h2.server.TcpServerThread.close(TcpServerThread.java:210)
    at org.h2.server.TcpServerThread.run(TcpServerThread.java:169)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
May 09, 2014 7:45:28 PM org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader initWebApplicationContext
SEVERE: Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'activitiInteractionService': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.activiti.engine.ProcessEngine com.service.ActivitiInteractionService.processEngine; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'processEngineServerMode': FactoryBean threw exception on object creation; nested exception is org.springframework.transaction.CannotCreateTransactionException: Could not open JDBC Connection for transaction; nested exception is org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: General error: "java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/h2/mvstore/db/TransactionStore$1" [50000-178]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:344)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:167)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.convert(DbException.java:290)
    at org.h2.server.TcpServerThread.sendError(TcpServerThread.java:222)
    at org.h2.server.TcpServerThread.run(TcpServerThread.java:155)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/h2/mvstore/db/TransactionStore$1
    at org.h2.mvstore.db.TransactionStore.getChanges(TransactionStore.java:511)
    at org.h2.mvstore.db.TransactionStore$Transaction.getChanges(TransactionStore.java:800)
    at org.h2.engine.Session.rollbackTo(Session.java:602)
    at org.h2.command.Command.executeUpdate(Command.java:278)
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcPreparedStatement.execute(JdbcPreparedStatement.java:199)
    at org.h2.server.TcpServer.addConnection(TcpServer.java:140)
    at org.h2.server.TcpServerThread.run(TcpServerThread.java:152)
    ... 1 more

    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:292)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1185)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:304)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:300)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:195)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:700)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:760)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:482)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:403)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4939)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5434)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:633)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:976)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1653)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.activiti.engine.ProcessEngine com.service.ActivitiInteractionService.processEngine; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'processEngineServerMode': FactoryBean threw exception on object creation; nested exception is org.springframework.transaction.CannotCreateTransactionException: Could not open JDBC Connection for transaction; nested exception is org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: General error: "java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/h2/mvstore/db/TransactionStore$1" [50000-178]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:344)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:167)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.convert(DbException.java:290)
    at org.h2.server.TcpServerThread.sendError(TcpServerThread.java:222)
    at org.h2.server.TcpServerThread.run(TcpServerThread.java:155)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/h2/mvstore/db/TransactionStore$1
    at org.h2.mvstore.db.TransactionStore.getChanges(TransactionStore.java:511)
    at org.h2.mvstore.db.TransactionStore$Transaction.getChanges(TransactionStore.java:800)
    at org.h2.engine.Session.rollbackTo(Session.java:602)
    at org.h2.command.Command.executeUpdate(Command.java:278)
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcPreparedStatement.execute(JdbcPreparedStatement.java:199)
    at org.h2.server.TcpServer.addConnection(TcpServer.java:140)
    at org.h2.server.TcpServerThread.run(TcpServerThread.java:152)
    ... 1 more

    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:508)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:289)
    ... 26 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'processEngineServerMode': FactoryBean threw exception on object creation; nested exception is org.springframework.transaction.CannotCreateTransactionException: Could not open JDBC Connection for transaction; nested exception is org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: General error: "java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/h2/mvstore/db/TransactionStore$1" [50000-178]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:344)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:167)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.convert(DbException.java:290)
    at org.h2.server.TcpServerThread.sendError(TcpServerThread.java:222)
    at org.h2.server.TcpServerThread.run(TcpServerThread.java:155)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/h2/mvstore/db/TransactionStore$1
    at org.h2.mvstore.db.TransactionStore.getChanges(TransactionStore.java:511)
    at org.h2.mvstore.db.TransactionStore$Transaction.getChanges(TransactionStore.java:800)
    at org.h2.engine.Session.rollbackTo(Session.java:602)
    at org.h2.command.Command.executeUpdate(Command.java:278)
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcPreparedStatement.execute(JdbcPreparedStatement.java:199)
    at org.h2.server.TcpServer.addConnection(TcpServer.java:140)
    at org.h2.server.TcpServerThread.run(TcpServerThread.java:152)
    ... 1 more

    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.doGetObjectFromFactoryBean(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:151)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.getObjectFromFactoryBean(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:103)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getObjectForBeanInstance(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1514)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:315)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:195)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1014)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:957)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:855)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:480)
    ... 28 more
Caused by: org.springframework.transaction.CannotCreateTransactionException: Could not open JDBC Connection for transaction; nested exception is org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: General error: "java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/h2/mvstore/db/TransactionStore$1" [50000-178]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:344)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:167)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.convert(DbException.java:290)
    at org.h2.server.TcpServerThread.sendError(TcpServerThread.java:222)
    at org.h2.server.TcpServerThread.run(TcpServerThread.java:155)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/h2/mvstore/db/TransactionStore$1
    at org.h2.mvstore.db.TransactionStore.getChanges(TransactionStore.java:511)
    at org.h2.mvstore.db.TransactionStore$Transaction.getChanges(TransactionStore.java:800)
    at org.h2.engine.Session.rollbackTo(Session.java:602)
    at org.h2.command.Command.executeUpdate(Command.java:278)
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcPreparedStatement.execute(JdbcPreparedStatement.java:199)
    at org.h2.server.TcpServer.addConnection(TcpServer.java:140)
    at org.h2.server.TcpServerThread.run(TcpServerThread.java:152)
    ... 1 more

    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager.doBegin(DataSourceTransactionManager.java:243)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.getTransaction(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:373)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate.execute(TransactionTemplate.java:130)
    at org.activiti.spring.SpringTransactionInterceptor.execute(SpringTransactionInterceptor.java:40)
    at org.activiti.engine.impl.interceptor.LogInterceptor.execute(LogInterceptor.java:32)
    at org.activiti.engine.impl.ProcessEngineImpl.<init>(ProcessEngineImpl.java:75)
    at org.activiti.engine.impl.cfg.ProcessEngineConfigurationImpl.buildProcessEngine(ProcessEngineConfigurationImpl.java:311)
    at org.activiti.spring.SpringProcessEngineConfiguration.buildProcessEngine(SpringProcessEngineConfiguration.java:60)
    at org.activiti.spring.ProcessEngineFactoryBean.getObject(ProcessEngineFactoryBean.java:56)
    at org.activiti.spring.ProcessEngineFactoryBean.getObject(ProcessEngineFactoryBean.java:32)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.doGetObjectFromFactoryBean(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:144)
    ... 36 more
Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: General error: "java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/h2/mvstore/db/TransactionStore$1" [50000-178]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:344)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:167)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.convert(DbException.java:290)
    at org.h2.server.TcpServerThread.sendError(TcpServerThread.java:222)
    at org.h2.server.TcpServerThread.run(TcpServerThread.java:155)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/h2/mvstore/db/TransactionStore$1
    at org.h2.mvstore.db.TransactionStore.getChanges(TransactionStore.java:511)
    at org.h2.mvstore.db.TransactionStore$Transaction.getChanges(TransactionStore.java:800)
    at org.h2.engine.Session.rollbackTo(Session.java:602)
    at org.h2.command.Command.executeUpdate(Command.java:278)
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcPreparedStatement.execute(JdbcPreparedStatement.java:199)
    at org.h2.server.TcpServer.addConnection(TcpServer.java:140)
    at org.h2.server.TcpServerThread.run(TcpServerThread.java:152)
    ... 1 more

    at org.h2.engine.SessionRemote.done(SessionRemote.java:610)
    at org.h2.engine.SessionRemote.initTransfer(SessionRemote.java:129)
    at org.h2.engine.SessionRemote.connectServer(SessionRemote.java:434)
    at org.h2.engine.SessionRemote.connectEmbeddedOrServer(SessionRemote.java:348)
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.<init>(JdbcConnection.java:107)
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.<init>(JdbcConnection.java:91)
    at org.h2.Driver.connect(Driver.java:74)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.SimpleDriverDataSource.getConnectionFromDriver(SimpleDriverDataSource.java:140)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.getConnectionFromDriver(AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.java:155)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.getConnection(AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.java:120)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager.doBegin(DataSourceTransactionManager.java:205)
    ... 46 more
```

Comment: For some reason it is not finding the H2 jar file. Do a manual maven install of h2 database.,

Comment: I see this as well. The application runs the first time, but for some reason restarting the application is not working with this error.

Comment: I have this same issue. Guess the only workaround is to downgrade

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34413/why-am-i-getting-a-noclassdeffounderror-in-java